# jsx unexpected identifier when running jest test

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, react-native-web, storyshots

when runnning jest test, error is as below.

```
  Demo
    ✕ should pass this demo test (3537ms)

  ● Demo › should pass this demo test

    /Users/johnzhou/Desktop/common-components/node_modules/react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/languages/prism/jsx.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import jsx from "refractor/lang/jsx.js";
                                                                                                    ^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter.js:54:35)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
```

It happens when I want to make a storyshots test for a storybook for react-native-web project.And the project is typescript project.
The case of unit test is very simple,

```
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots'
describe('Demo', () => {
  it('should pass this demo test', () => {
    initStoryshots();
  });
})
```

The package.json of project is as below.

```
"private": true,
    "name": "docs",
    "version": "0.11.7",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "build-storybook --docs -o ./dist -c ./.storybook",
        "start": "start-storybook --docs -p 9001 -c ./.storybook",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "test": "jest --no-cache -u"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@storybook/addon-docs": "^5.3.0-beta.31",
        "@storybook/addon-options": "^5.3.0-beta.31",
        "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^5.3.7",
        "@storybook/cli": "^5.3.0-beta.31",
        "@storybook/react": "^5.3.0-beta.31",
        "@storybook/theming": "^5.3.0-beta.31",
        "@types/react": "^16.8.8",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.57.39",
        "core-js": "^3.6.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^16.9.0",
        "react-native": "^0.61.2",
        "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
        "react-native-web": "0.11.7",
        "typescript": "^3.3.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-require-context-hook": "^1.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
        "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.3.3",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^4.1.18",
        "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^4.1.18",
        "@storybook/addon-notes": "^4.1.10",
        "@storybook/addon-options": "^4.1.18",
        "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^4.1.18",
        "@storybook/react": "^4.1.18",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.25",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "0.11.7",
        "file-loader": "3.0.1",
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "jest-junit": "^8.0.0",
        "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
        "jsdom": "^15.1.1",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
        "react-native-web": "^0.10.1",
        "react-native-web-image-loader": "0.0.6",
        "ts-jest": "^24.1.0",
        "url-loader": "^2.2.0",
        "webpack": "^4.41.2"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native-web",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "ts",
            "tsx",
            "js",
            "jsx",
            "json"
        ],
        "setupFiles": [
            "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"
        ],
        "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
        "testMatch": [
            "<rootDir>/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
        ],
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
            "\\.snap$",
            "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
        ],
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.([j|t]sx?)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
            "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest",
            "^.+\\.mdx?$": "@storybook/addon-docs/jest-transform-mdx"
        },
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
            "!**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "coverageReporters": [
            "text-summary",
            "json-summary",
            "lcov",
            "html"
        ]
    }
}
```

The babelrc of project is as below.

```
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-typescript", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins":[
    ["@babel/proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
    "react-native-web"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["require-context-hook"]
    }
  }
}
```

This problem troubles me a long time, who can help me.Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like babel is not correctly setup.

Comment: Your meaning is that presets is not correct?

Comment: Not necessarily the presets. Can you share your package.json file?

Comment: I updated the content  about package.json of question just moment and please have a see for it.Thank you very much!